# Force FullCalendar weekly dayheader on day mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

So I'm using FullCalendar v4 library for reservation system, and I need to override DayHeader while using day-mode (`timeGridDay` or `timeGridWeek` with duration set to `{days: 1}`). Basically I have this sketch:

[image]

I want to get day-mode system (as I told) with week-based DayHeader (because I use days labels in my JavaScript code for day switching). I want just to display single day in calendar, with preserving header (header that displays 7 days).

I was trying to override header to `duration: {days: 7}`, copy header using jQuery `.html()` method, and then change `duration` to `{days: 1}` and paste header using `.html()` on the same div. But changing duration using method from GitHub destroy cells style alignment, so it does not display nicely as you were using `duration: {days: 1}` on Calendar init.

What can I do? Thanks in advance for solutions.

@EDIT:

I want to mention that the answer how to restyle FullCalendar (set automatically width for DayHeader cells (labels)) after changing durations is also adequate for me and fits into my wished solution - so if you have something in mind, tell me.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. You say "display a single day in calendar with preserving header that displays 7 days"). So you want to show only the events of one day, but show 7 days in the header? I'm not sure it makes sense. Your screenshot doesn't show any events at all, so it's a little bit unclear. Or are you just asking about changing the field above the days which shows a specific date?

Comment: I don't know if you can use the https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/titleFormat settings to adjust it the way you want, have you tried anything with that?

Comment: @ADyson "So you want to show only the events of one day, but show 7 days in the header?" - yes, that's what I want todo. I tried solution from this: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5581 but it does not work nicely since it spoils cells and whole fullcalendar (it wrongly overrides cell style width).

Also I will be trying solution mentioned in your link, thank you very much!

Comment: `yes, that's what I want todo`...can I ask why?? this sounds like a great way to confuse users, and/or waste space on the screen.

Comment: I agree with you, but I want to implement day-switching using day labels in the header (just by clicking the day you wish in the week), and also I want to mark the current single day label by changing background color - it should make calendar readable for user. I know that I can change single day using `calendar.gotoDate(date)` method, so I only need to find way with the header. Do you know any solution?

Comment: Why not just add a standard date picker control?

Comment: Because that's is client wish, not mine :P I also added datepicker control that works, but they requested also day-label switching, so I'm going to find solution anyway.

Comment: Clients don't always consider all the possible ways to achieve a particular goal. If the specify the method rather than the goal, then usually they've gone to far. You're the programmer, it's part of your job to find the best solution, not just implement exactly whatever the client _thinks_ they want. Clients are not user experience designers! Also often, in my experience, if you give them an alternative way to achieve what they want, and it's also quicker and cheaper to implement, they usually like that :-)

Comment: Thanks for advice, I will discuss it with him.

Answer (score 1):

So, I resolved my problem by using this code:

```js
if(view.viewSpec.type === 'customDayGrid'){
    let views = calendar.getOption('views');
    views.customDayGrid.duration.days = 1;
    calendar.setOption('views', views);
}

setTimeout(() => {
    $(headerSel).html(getHeaderHTML);
    calendar.updateSize();
}, 100)
```

I wish I didn't used `setTimeout` but I don't know how to resolve it different way - but it works, so I think it closes my issue.